# Android form validation

Tags: java, android

i am new to android. I have a form which stores values to shared preferences on click. i need to validate these values first then submits.
i have tried a simple mechanism, but it does not work for me.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {                                   //proceed button

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String fname = e1.getText().toString();
            String lname = e2.getText().toString();
            String phone = e3.getText().toString();
            String adress = e4.getText().toString();
            String email = e5.getText().toString();
            if(fname==null)
            {
                e1.setError("null");
            }
            else
            {
            Editor ed = sp.edit();
            ed.putString("fname", fname);
            ed.putString("lname", lname);
            ed.putString("phone", phone);
            ed.putString("adress", adress);
            ed.putString("email", email);

            ed.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            }
```

here if clause does not works, values are save weather fname is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fname` is not `null` but it is empty, so use `fname.isEmpty()` instead of `fname == null`

```
if(fname.isEmpty())
{
    e1.setError("null");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `EditText` e1 is empty, the following expression will result in an empty string `""`. It won't be `null`.

```
String fname = e1.getText().toString();
```

So, check it as follows:

```
if("".equals(fname)) {
    e1.setError("empty");
}
```